# Separate APIs for User Login?

Tags: rest, api, google-plus, facebook-login

I need to create an API for login for my website.
There can be 3 ways for a user to login:

1. via Username/Password combination
2. via Google+ Token and EmailId
3. via FB Token and EMailId

Should there be a single API for this or should all the above exist as separate APIs? The output for the Login API will always be a token that will be used to make further authenticated requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more a matter of taste. I'd have a generic ProviderAuthentication API endpoint that receives a token id and another Authentication API endpoint that receives username & password. But you can also aim towards [REST level 1](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level1) and have some generic Login resource (that contains username, password, providerToken & token properties) to work with a generic Login API endpoint.